# Linq to SQL: Unable to Successively insert 2 objects that compare equal

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have a table Size, and I have overloaded GetHashCode and Equals on the corresponding object generated by Linq to SQL.

I am executing the following code:

```
Size s = new Size();
data_context.Sizes.InsertOnSubmit(s);
data_context.SubmitChanges();
s = new Size
{
    Diameter=1
};
data_context.Sizes.InsertOnSubmit(s);
data_context.SubmitChanges();
s = new Size
{
    Diameter=1
};
data_context.Sizes.InsertOnSubmit(s);
data_context.SubmitChanges();
```

On the third SubmitChanges, I get an InvalidOperationException with the message

> "Cannot add an entity that already exists."

If I rerun the program I can add the first two again but not the third. I have no clue what's going on, could someone give me a pointer?

If I only override Size.Equals or Size.GetHashCode, this problem doesn't arise, but it does when I override both.

The Equals and GetHashCode override are as follow (but really any kind of method that implement value semantics lead to the same behavior):

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    Size p = obj as Size;
    if ((System.Object)p == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return p.Diameter == Diameter;
}
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Diameter?.GetHashCode()??0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> I have overloaded GetHashCode and Equals on the corresponding object generated by Linq to SQL.

If you overloaded those so that two `Size` entities with the same properties are considered equal, then this is working as expected; LINQ to SQL uses equality checks to determine if two objects refer to the same record to keep things in sync.

Why did you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the first place? Simply removing those overrides will avoid this issue if you're wanting to be able to insert similar `Size` objects.

Comment: Ok, can you please tell me where this is documented? Also, can you explain why I can insert the first and second ones (that are already "duplicates" of an existing item)?

Comment: I overrid Size.Equals because it is convenient for me at other places, and I overrid Size.GetHashCode because I have read it is better to override both. I sure can get rid of it but I would like to understand what happens really...

Comment: @Ernest_Galbrun - Perhaps you should add your implementation of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to your question.  That might help people in answering.  Also, in your first example, you are not setting the value of `Diameter`.  What is it's default?  Can you also show that class?

Comment: There's a difference between duplicate records in the _database_ versus duplicate _objects_. The first two inserts are inserting distinct objects in the database. The third is the same object as the second (because of the `Equals` override), so Linq to SQL considers it an entity that has already been added.

Comment: The reason it cares is because of the object tracking feature. When calling `InsertOnSubmit`, it starts tracking the object as needing to be inserted later on, and calling `InsertOnSubmit` twice doesn't make sense to the framework. To explore the MSDN docs, you can start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.objecttrackingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I didn't include the definition of Equals and GetHashCode because they are pretty application specific. I added the ones I use for the tests in my question.. The default value for Diameter is null. I don't set it in the first example to show that I can insert 2 records in a single run as long as they are "different", and I still can't see why...

Comment: @Jacob Sorry Jacob but I don't understand the rationale of that behavior: Why wouldn't it make sense to insert two objects that compare equals? And why would this behavior only occur when I override both Equals and GetHashCode, and not when I override only one?

Comment: Imagine calling `InsertOnSubmit` with the exact same object twice; what would you expect to happen? Some may want that object to be inserted once, others to insert two duplicate rows. It's ambiguous. MS wisely chose to throw an exception if you try to mark a duplicate object to be inserted twice, and `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is how they find duplicates. If you didn't override those, the default object equality would be used. `GetHashCode` factors in most likely because to-be-inserted objects are kept in a hash-based container (`HashMap` or `Dictionary`).

Comment: tl;dr. `Equals` and `GetHashCode` are used within .NET for determining object uniqueness, so if two separate objects appear identical to LINQ to SQL, it thinks they're references to the same entity. I'd suggest not overriding `Equals` and writing a separate equality method for _your_ purposes. The other methods are .NET essentials that you usually shouldn't mess with.

Comment: @Jacob What bothers me is that the framework is trying to enforce a value semantic (sure, I provided it) on the application level, but that would only make sense if it was also enforced in the database. As long as two identical records are allowed by the database, it makes no sense to check identity using value semantic in the application, that's what ReferenceEquals is for. And sure I can (and will) dissociate my value comparison logic from the Linq to SQL class. Thanks for the explanation though!